# Can we "do up" or "button up" a single button?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, idioms, idiomatic-language, phrase-choice

I know we can "do up" or "button up" multiple buttons, but can we use these phrases when we talk about one single button as well? For example, is it correct to say,

> "One of the buttons on your shirt is undone. Do it up."

or

> "One of the buttons on your shirt is undone. Button it up."

I think those phrases are probably only used when referring to multiple buttons. What do you think?

Comment: You can "button up your lip" and that has no actual buttons at all.

Comment: if it were relating to "multiple buttons", it would be "button **them** up", wouldn't it?

Comment: I know that *do it/do that/do so* are common and *do* serves as a substitute verb for the previously stated verb. However, *button (sth) up* seems a phrasal verb.. (*do it up* sounds weird to me, Idk)

Comment: The verbification of nouns (or nounification of verbs, depending) of ***Button that button**!* doesn't have anywhere near the grace of Shakespeare's ***Grace me no grace, nor uncle me no uncle.***

Comment: @AndrewTobilko There's nothing 'weird' about _do up a button_ (not in my British English, at least).

Answer (score 2):

It's the shirt you "button up", not the buttons.

So "button it up" refers to the shirt (singular) not the buttons (however many or few) there are of them.